# How to use localStorage in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am using simple Vue app to get data and then present it in a table. Now I created an OK button, where I can change whether one thing is copmlete or not ( similar to todo app).

But how could I save the changes?

This is my code:

```
declare var Vue: any;
declare var axios: any;

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#appnew',
    data: {
        message: '',
        status: [],
        id: '',
    },
    created: function () {
        this.loadQuote();
    },
    methods: {
        loadQuote: function () {
            const id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
            this.status = 'Loading...';
            axios.get('path' + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.status = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    vm.status = 'An error occured.' + error;
                });
        },
        toggleDone(statu) {
            statu.done = !statu.done
        },
    },
});
```

Under the toggleDone method I am changing whether it is done or not, so I guess I should add there to also save the changes? Using localStorage? Any ideas anyone?

Thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd have to save the value to `localStorage`, retrieve it, then do what you want with it:

```
toggleDone(statu) {
    statu.done = !statu.done
    localStorage.setItem('statu', statu.done);
}
```

```
const statu = localStorage.getItem('statu');
```

Comment: You could set a data property called `statu` then in the `created` hook do `this.statu = localStorage.getItem('statu')`

Comment: thanks again, but this doesn't seem to work for me. Under the loadQuote method I am getting a json and under the toggleDone I am changing one variable in my data (done 
 boolean). Everything until then works, but what I need is to save the changes of the boolean to the localstorage, so when I refresh the page, it still has the new boolean values.

Comment: I don't see where `toggleDone` is being called so I don't know what `statu.done` is referring to. All you need to do is retrieve the data from `localStorage` in the `created` hook and set it to the previous data property it was set to when clicked

Comment: the toggleDone is called in .cshtml with a button:
<button v-on:click="toggleDone(statu)">
                        <span v-if="statu.done == false">
                            OK
                        </span><span v-else>
                        OKs
                        </span>
                    </button>

Comment: What is `statu` though?

Comment: first in the table I am calling it v-for="statu in status", so that it takes the variables from my vue app

Comment: If you're fetching from a database, you'd need to change the data there. Otherwise, it just resets every time `loadQuote` is called.